# uninterrupted execution of Cpp Linux code

Tags: c++, linux, time, critical-section

Hi is there a method on which I can make my code safe from other OS interrupts etc in Linux  GNU? For example if I have the code below and I need to find the exact execution time without other things interrupting my code.

I have already looked into `pthread_mutex_lock(&cs_mutex);` but wasn't able to stop other operations to run.

```
while(1){
//start some method to block other OS overheads
c_start=clock();
some_function();
c_end=clock();
//stop OS overhead block
//calculate time 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that? If you could, that would mean your system freezes completely while your code runs. No updates to the screen, no mouse movements, nothing. Better use a profiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [clock_gettime](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime):

```
timespec ts;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &ts);
```

It won't prevent other processes interrupting your code but it will only time the execution of ***your*** process taking such interrupts into account.

Answer (score 0):

You must not lock the the whole system to get the elapsed time which only your prog uses. If you take a look at the simple `time` command, you can see that you OS knows which time goes to your application and which time was used for other actions of the system:

```
[krud@unknown001742754ee6 ~]$ time sleep 1

real    0m1.025s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.001s
```

As you can see, the sleep command takes a bit more then one second, but only consumes "nothing" in user level but a few microseconds in system mode.

If you want to see how much time each function of your code needs, use a profiler like `gprof`. This tool give you also the exact time consumed by your functions of your prog, nearly independent from interruptions from other actions of you box.